# Deleting all the lines before a WORD on sublime text

Tags: file, text, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I have a Big Text File that contains +1M Lines

and there's a word `johnd` on line 45280525. I want to delete all the lines before it.

How I can do that using Sublime Text?

Note that Notepad++ won't work with this file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can go to the line using  `menu > Goto > Goto Line...`

or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>.

You might be looking for the `Mark` feature:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to go to the last line you want to select, by number.
- `Edit > Mark > Set Mark` to set your selection-end marker.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd>) to go to the first line you want to select.
- `Edit > Mark > Delete to Mark`

Otherwise, you can write a code for open file as text  ... delete the rows you need, save and ... close.

Comment: i wont go to line i said i want to delete all the lines before the word " johnd "

Comment: In my experience you can just do "Delete to Mark" immediately after "Set Mark"

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a hack, and it only works if there is at least one type of brackets that are not used in the text.

1. Crate an opening bracket at the beginning of the file (`(`, `[` or `{`).
2. Ctrl+F, search for your word (" johnd ")
3. Create a closing bracket before the word, corresponding to the opening bracket (`)`, `]` or `}`)
4. Shift+Ctrl+M, jump to opposite bracket (Ctrl+M) while selecting text (Shift).
5. Delete selected text and the brackets.

There's probably a better way to do this, but it's the solution I could think of.

Answer (score 0):

If your file turns out to be too big to edit in Sublime Text, at a Linux command line you could do:

```
sed -ne '/johnd/,$p' myfile.txt > edited.txt
mv edited.txt myfile.txt
```

That prints all of the lines from the one matching `johnd` to the end of the file. The output is captured to a new file and then renamed back to replace the original file.

Answer (score 0):

1. Place your cursor at the start of the first line you want to keep (e.g. with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>)
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd> to select all text up to the beginning of the file
3. <kbd>⌫ Delete</kbd>

Comment: This takes about 12 seconds for 12 million lines of length around 40 on my (slow) PC